# how to set the number of bing search result page to 50 in cookie

Tags: python, cookies, header

When I change the number of results on each page from 50 to 10, I find out that the number shows below changed to 10c.But When I put it in header like this:

"Cookie":"SRCHHPGUSR=CW=1241&CH=780&DPR=2&UTC=480&NEWWND=0&NRSLT=10c&SRCHLANG=&AS=1&NNT=1&HIS=1&HAP=0"

or

"SRCHHPGUSR":"CW=1241&CH=780&DPR=2&UTC=480&NEWWND=0&NRSLT=10c&SRCHLANG=&AS=1&NNT=1&HIS=1&HAP=0"

Both failed,just remaining returns 10. So does anybody here know how to set the number to 50?Thanks!

SRCHHPGUSR=CW=1241&CH=780&DPR=2&UTC=480&NEWWND=0&NRSLT=10c&SRCHLANG=&AS=1&NNT=1&HIS=1&HAP=0

Comment: `requests.get('https://www.bing.com/search?q=test', cookies={'SRCHHPGUSR': 'NRSLT=50'}).content.count('class="b_algo')` returns about 50 results, which seems right.

Comment: @Blender Great!Thanks very much! You should answer it directly and I will choose your answer and give you an upvote. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

[@Blender](https://stackoverflow.com/users/464744/blender) has given the right answer ,Thanks very much!

```
requests.get('https://www.bing.com/search?q=test', cookies={'SRCHHPGUSR': 'NRSLT=50'}).content.count('class="b_algo')
```

returns about 50 results, which seems right.

Answer (score -2):

requests.get('https://www.bing.com/search?q=test', cookies={'SRCHHPGUSR': 'NRSLT=50'}).content.count('class="b_algo')